# Trouble scanning list for duplicates

Tags: python, traceback

Hey so i want to scan this text file of emails and if two of the same emails pop up i want it to be printed if only 1 email is on the list i dont want it to be printed.

It worked for a different text file but now its saying traceback error???

```
#note make sure found.txt and list.txt are in the 'include' for pycharmfrom collect ions import Counter

print("Welcome DADDY")

with open('myheritage-1-million.txt') as f:
    c=Counter(c.strip().lower() for c in f if c.strip()) #for case-insensitive search
    for line in c:
        if c[line] > 1:
            print(line)
```

ERROR:

```
rs/dcaputo/PycharmProjects/searchtoolforrhys/venv/include/search.py
Welcome DADDY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dcaputo/PycharmProjects/searchtoolforrhys/venv/include/search.py", line 5, in <module>
    c = Counter(c.strip().lower() for c in f if c.strip()) #for case-insensitive search
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 566, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 653, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
  File "/Users/dcaputo/PycharmProjects/searchtoolforrhys/venv/include/search.py", line 5, in <genexpr>
    c = Counter(c.strip().lower() for c in f if c.strip()) #for case-insensitive search
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 2668: invalid continuation byte

Process finished with exit code 1
```

a list of all emails that are shown up 2 times in that whole text file

Comment: There's unicode in the file. You can try/except it, or handle it with decoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is the error message at the end:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 2668: invalid continuation byte`

This error can occur when trying to read a non-text file as text. Your file could be corrupted somehow and has some data (at position 2668) in it that can't be read as text.

Comment: Hey i fixed the error, my txt file of all the emails was just on read only. now i runned it and it spit out 11000 emails out of the 100k email list. Some of the ones it spit out do match and somes dont? is something wrong with my code? is there a way i can write if there is 1 email like dan@gmail.com and then down 241 lines dan@gmail.com repeats again it will then print it????

Comment: You mean that some of the emails it prints are duplicates and some are not?